# First principle derivation for torsional constant

Tags: materials, structural-engineering, steel

For torsional constant, analytical formulas are available for some standard steel sections as shown in this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_constant).

But what about arbitrary shapes? How can I obtain the formulas for torsional constants? If no such formulas are available, are there any first principles that I can use to deduce the approximate formulas or FEM calculation for torsional constant?

Note: a related question about the FEM formulation of torsional constant is being asked [here](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6622/how-do-i-use-fem-to-derive-the-torsional-constant-of-an-arbitrarily-shape).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For arbitrary thick-walled shapes, there are no generic formulas available. You have to calculate the torsion constant using numerical methods, e.g. FEM or BEM.

Comment: Do you have any pointers on how to derive FEM solution for torsional constant ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. But I just found this document that seems to explain how to calculate the torsional constant numerically: http://people.virginia.edu/~ttb/torsion.pdf

Comment: Do you have any pointers on how to derive FEM solution for torsional constant ? – Graviton.  This seems like a really, really good stand-alone question.  I'd recommend you ask that on its own.

Comment: @Mark, I've asked my question [here](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/6622/3353)